# Inherit attribute info of class in method

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I've the following attribute:

```
class HandlerAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string MainName { get; private set; }
    public string SubName { get; private set; }

    public HandlerAttribute(string pValue, bool pIsMain) {
        if (pIsMain) MainName = pValue;
        else SubName = pValue;
    }
}
```

And this is the way I use the attribute

```
[Handler("SomeMainName", true)]
class Class1 {

    [Handler("SomeSubName", false)]
    void HandleThis() {
       Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that I import the MainName value from the parent class attribute into the method defined inside the class.

I hope that someone can help me with this :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to write a helper method for this, basically it isn't possible by default because you don't have access to the attribute's target.

#### Code

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class HandlerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string MainName { get; private set; }
    public string SubName { get; private set; }

    public HandlerAttribute(string pValue, bool pIsMain) {
        if (pIsMain) MainName = pValue;
        else SubName = pValue;
    }

    public HandlerAttributeData GetData(MemberInfo info)
    {
        if (info is Type)
        {
            return new HandlerAttributeData(MainName, null);
        }

        HandlerAttribute attribute = (HandlerAttribute)info.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HandlerAttribute), true)[0];

        return new HandlerAttributeData(attribute.MainName, SubName);
    }
}


class HandlerAttributeData
{
    public string MainName { get; private set; }
    public string SubName { get; private set; }

    public HandlerAttributeData(String mainName, String subName)
    {
        MainName = mainName;
        SubName = subName;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
        HandlerAttribute att = (HandlerAttribute)typeof(App).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HandlerAttribute), true)[0];
        HandlerAttributeData data = att.GetData(typeof(App));
```

You can use it with any member and if you write a extension method you can make it even shorter.

Comment: It seems that it's more complex than I thought it would be. Thanks for the examples, but for me it's easier to just do HandlerAttribute(string pMainName, string pSubName) :)

Comment: @Diamondo25 That's ok, in large scale projects it would be easier ( You even don't need that boolean anymore ). But we both answered your question so it would be fine if you mark one question as correct. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Update:
You may use this extension method as well.

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    public static string GetMainName(this Class1 class1)
    {
        System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(class1.GetType());  // reflection

        foreach (System.Attribute attr in attrs)
        {
            if (attr is HandlerAttribute)
            {
                string mainName = (attr as HandlerAttribute).MainName;
                return mainName;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No MainName Attribute");
    }
}
```

Now after coding the extension method you may use it on any Class1 type object;

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
            string a =c1.GetMainName();
```

Or you may use it directly.

```
 public class HandlerAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string MainName { get; private set; }
    public string SubName { get; private set; }

    public HandlerAttribute(string pValue, bool pIsMain)
    {
        if (pIsMain) MainName = pValue;
        else SubName = pValue;
    }
}

[Handler("SomeMainName", true)]
class Class1
{

    [Handler("SomeSubName", false)]
    public void HandleThis()
    {
        System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(this.GetType());  // reflection

        foreach (System.Attribute attr in attrs)
        {
            if (attr is HandlerAttribute)
            {
                string mainName = (attr as HandlerAttribute).MainName;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a pain in the *ss for many functions. Do you have a better method?

Comment: you may write an extension method, or your base class may have this function. If you prefer one over the other I may help.